# Recommended ways to read certain things in a text file

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to figure out the best way to read data from a file. I figured out a way but as a jr. I know it's not the best way to go about things. Here is what my text file looks like:

```
--------Text File text.txt---------
username: nothingeag
accesscode: 123456
value: 74
email: test@testing.com
--------End of File----------------
```

And here is what I came up with:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace FileSystem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var username = "";
            var accesscodeStr = "";
            var accesscode = 0;
            var valueStr = "";
            var value = 0;
            var email = "";
            var path = @"C:\Users\jthompson\text.txt";

            //Read Lines
            username = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(0).Take(1).First();
            accesscodeStr = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1).Take(1).First();
            valueStr = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(2).Take(1).First();
            email = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(3).Take(1).First();

            //Trim retrieved data
            username = username.Substring(10);
            accesscodeStr = accesscodeStr.Substring(12);
            valueStr = valueStr.Substring(7);
            email = email.Substring(7);

            //Parse the INT values
            accesscode = Int32.Parse(accesscodeStr);
            value = Int32.Parse(valueStr);

            //Display the Data
            Console.WriteLine(accesscode);
            Console.WriteLine(email);
            Console.WriteLine(username);
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs exactly what I need:

```
123456
test@testing.com
nothingeag
74
```

What is the best way to go about reading specific items like this in a text file?

Comment: File.ReadAllLines will give you an array with your lines. Then you don't need all those ReadLines,Skip, Take and First, but just the line index

Comment: I'm confused why you read all the text into `content` and then never use it. Once you have that all you need to do is split the resulting string by newline characters and further split those based on some separator (possibly `:`). As it is now, you're reading in the entire file five times just to get the information you want.

Comment: Or alternatively, what @Steve said, then you don't have to split the newlines and just have to deal with extracting the data from each line.

Comment: Not entirely sure what your question is here. If you have a piece of code that outputs exactly what you need, then what is the question?

Comment: `File.ReadLines(path).Select(line => line.Split(": ")[1]).ToList()`

Comment: whoops, the var content wasn't supposed to be in there.

Comment: What exactly does Take(1).First() do? I couldn't find good documentation on it that wasn't confusing, and the code doesn't work without it.

Comment: Take(n) is an IEnumerable function, that returns a collections first n numbers as a new IEnumerable collection. First() just returns the first element in an IEnumerable.

Comment: Basicly: Take(1).First() returns your first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input file structure is static that means it wont change the order; you can use the below instead of your //ReadLines code.

```
        var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        var dataSet = allLines.Select(line => line.Trim().Split(' ')[1]).ToArray();
        // Add conditional checks regarding the length of the dataset and any thing else.
        var userName = dataSet[0];
        var accesscode = Convert.ToInt32(dataSet[1]);
        var value = Convert.ToInt32(dataSet[2]);
        var email = dataSet[3];

        // Then your console.writeline statements here.
```

If you are unsure of the order, you can use dictionary to store the both parts of line split one for key and other for value.  And then print them.

Comment: This works wonderfully and is WAY less code than what I have. Thanks for the tips everyone!

Comment: @JosephThompson It's not always the size of the code.. ;)

Comment: That is very true

Comment: It would probably be better to split on the `:` instead of space, then call `Trim()`. The current data doesn't look like it would ever have spaces, but if it was changed in the future to add something that does have spaces then you'll run into problems.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are making many mistakes:

- You are enumerating throught the file MANY times. Read it, store it, than you can make operations on the stored data.
- Don't use hardcoded substrings, use string.Split instead.
- There is nothing that assures you that those data is what you are anticipating. The number could well be a string, than your program would crash.

Here is a simple implementation of the upper ideas:

```
string[] fileInput = File.ReadAllLines(path);

string usernameString = fileInput[0].Split(": ")[1];
string accessCodeString = fileInput[1].Split(": ")[1];
string valueString = fileInput[2].Split(": ")[1];
string emailString = fileInput[3].Split(": ")[1];

int accessCode;    
if (!int.TryParse(accessCodeString, out accessCode))
{
     //Do something when accesscode is not int.
}

int value;    
if (!int.TryParse(accessCodeString, out value))
{
     //Do something when value is not int.
}

Console.WriteLine(accesscode);
Console.WriteLine(emailString);
Console.WriteLine(usernameString);
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

This is not a perfect solution, but it is in the right direction.

Comment: Actually OPs method `ReadLines` is better than `ReadAllLines` because it lazily reads the contents.

Comment: Yeah, like 4 times instead of once. And I said that it isn't a perfect solution, a StreamReader would be a hull lot better

Comment: `ReadLines()` uses a `StreamReader` underneath, and doesn't load the entire file at once. `ReadAllLines()` also uses `StreamReader`, but it loads the entire file into memory before returning the result. Not much of a problem for this specific case, but worth noting.

Comment: Yeah, but it has to read the whole file 4 times if you are calling it 4 times.

Comment: Correct, and no one was saying he should call it 4 times like he was, just that it could be better to use it for performance.

Answer (score -2):

I know this looks a bit goofy, but the Microsoft.VisualBasic assemblies have some great resources for reading text files.  This was really quick and dirty.  I'm just using ':' as a delimiter as others have suggested.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace SandBox
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> outputStrings = new List<string>();
            string path = @"C:\Users\oa971d\Desktop\textSample.txt";

            using (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser parser =
                new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(path))
            {
                parser.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited;
                parser.SetDelimiters(":"); //.csv
                                           //parser.SetDelimiters("\t"); //tab delimited .txt

              while(!parser.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                    if(fields.Length>1)
                        outputStrings.Add(fields[1]);
                }        
            }
            foreach(string s in outputStrings)
            { Console.WriteLine(s); }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this isn't a good solution by any means, but could one of the down voters give me some feedback?